# Stretching table cell text to both sides

Tags: html, alignment, html-table, cell

I have a html table cell with the following data:

```
<td>0/12 0%</td>
```

which shows like this:

http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/6008/captureuhe.jpg

what I want to do is move the % number (with the sign) to the most left side of the cell.

i.e:
http://img441.imageshack.us/img441/1259/capture2ee.jpg

(don't mind the numbers)

How can I achive this?
BTW, the entire table is with css direction: rtl.

Comment: Why not split it into two table cells? That's basically what this is.

Comment: I tried to avoid it :)
I can have it in another cell and than add a class to that cell to hide the border on the right...

Comment: The images are no longer available making the question unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td><div class="right">0/12</div> <div class="left">0%</div></td>
```

CSS file:

```
.right{
position:relative;
margin:0;
padding:0;
float:right;
}
.left{
position:relative;
margin:0;
padding:0;
float:left;
}
```

Comment: Awasme! just what i was looking for!